# Node.js: Spawning an echo process with the ">" flag

Tags: node.js, file-io, echo

I am looking to spawn an echo process to write some text to a "file".

*The `fs` package is off limits because the "file" is a communication pathway for a linux driver.

Below is my code to just see if I can get an `echo` process working with writing to a normal file however the `spawn` doesn't appear to like the `>` flag. Any ideas?

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

echo = spawn('echo', ["test", ">", __dirname+"/test.txt"]);

echo.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log('ls error', err);
});

echo.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

echo.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});

echo.on('close', function (code) {
    console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```

Right now I just get the following output with no written file:

```
stdout: test > <*PATH*>/test.txt

child process exited with code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just creating a bash file (`echo-test.sh`) with the following contents:

```
echo "test" > <*PATH*>/test.txt
```

and executed in node like such:

```
echo = spawn('bash', [__dirname+"/echo-test.sh"]);
```